# Computing rolling average and standard deviation by dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the below table where I will need to compute the rolling average and standard deviation based on the dates. I have listed below the tables and expected results. I am trying to compute the rolling average for an id based on date. rollAvgA is computed based on metricA. For example, for the first occurrence of id for a particular date the result should return zero as it does not have any preceding values. Please let me know how this can be accomplished?

Current Table :

```
Date       id     metricA  
8/1/2019   100       2    
8/2/2019   100       3
8/3/2019   100       2
8/1/2019   101       2    
8/2/2019   101       3
8/3/2019   101       2
8/4/2019   101       2
```

Expected Table :

```
Date       id     metricA   rollAvgA  
8/1/2019   100       2         0
8/2/2019   100       3         2.5
8/3/2019   100       2         2.3
8/1/2019   101       2         0
8/2/2019   101       3         2.5
8/3/2019   101       2         2.3
8/4/2019   101       2         2.25
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a cumulative average.  This is basically:

```
select t.*,
       avg(metricA * 1.0) over (partition by id order by date) as rollingavg
from t;
```

The only caveat is that the first value is an average of one value.  To handle this, use a `case` expression:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by id order by date) > 1
             then avg(metricA * 1.0) over (partition by id order by date)
             else 0
        end) as rollingavg
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guidance. May I know why have you multiplied metricA by 1.0?

Comment: @VibrantLearner . . . `metricA` looks like it could be an integer and SQL server returns an integer for the average of integers.